# Crystal Report last three years in text objects using formula

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

I want to make something like that using formula

[image: the years are Changing according to this year]

The years are changing according to this year

I am a completely Beginner

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I am a completely beginner with crystal report as i said but i searched a lot for the answer and i couldn't find any thing that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can piece it together with the following bits. **See the CR help text for all the functions below if you don't understand how they work or want more details**.

1. The `DateAdd()` function will allow you to add or subtract certain units of time to/from a DateTime. For example, if you want to get the date three years ago, you can use `DateAdd('yyyy',-3,CurrentDate)`
2. Printing a date can be done via the `ToText()` function. To only print the year portion of the DateTime field, you can use `ToText(CurrentDate,'yyyy')` which will give you '2014'
3. In CR, the newline character is `chr(13)`. Concatenate that onto a string to print a newline wherever you'd like.

EDIT: Since you already implemented it in C#, here's one possible CR solution:

```
" : " + totext(dateadd('yyyy',-3,currentdate),'yyyy') + chr(13) +
" : " + totext(dateadd('yyyy',-2,currentdate),'yyyy') + chr(13) +
" : " + totext(dateadd('yyyy',-1,currentdate),'yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank for helping i did it using c#